# sed + how to comment parameter that start in beginning of line even if parameter start with tab or spaces

Tags: sed, regular-expression

we have the following file

```
more /tmp/file
    number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are
  LOG "number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are"

echo "number_of_cars_are are $number_of_cars_are"

     grep number_of_cars_are /tmp/test
```

we want to comment only the line that start with `number_of_cars_are=` & in case line is already comment then sed should ignore

so we did the following

```
sed  '/^[^#].*^[[:space:]]*number_of_cars_are=/ s/^/#/' /tmp/file
```

but still the line - number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are remained the same

expected results

```
more /tmp/file
#    number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are
  LOG "number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are"

echo "number_of_cars_are are $number_of_cars_are"

     grep number_of_cars_are /tmp/test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you’re using to match the lines has two start-of-line anchors (`^`), so the second one will only match actual `^` symbols. If you remove the `^` before `[[:space:]]`, the expression will match, but too much:

```
#    number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are
#  LOG "number_of_cars_are=$number_of_cars_are"
```

`LOG "` matches `.*` so it’s accepted. I would drop the start of the expression:

```
sed  '/^[[:space:]]*number_of_cars_are=/ s/^/#/'
```

This matches any line starting with any number of whitespace characters (including none), followed by `number_of_cars_are=`. Commented lines won’t match this so they won’t be processed again, and lines starting directly with `number` will match.

Comment: Ha, you beat me there. Actually, your RegExp is more efficient.

Comment: @Navaro tab is part of `[:space:]`.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Thanks for the info: why not `\s` instead of `[:space:]` is it a portability issue?

Comment: @Navaro IIRC `[:space:]` is allowed in BREs, whereas `\s` isn’t portably, although GNU sed handles it.